# What is the proper workflow for creating city landscapes for use with RealityKit

Tags: arkit, realitykit, usdz

I'm learning up on `RealityKit` and trying to create a city landscape.

Watched this video from Apple and downloaded the associated project talking about `RealityComposer`

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/605

My initial goal is to create a city street with tall buildings and a controllable character which can walk around the streets and perform tasks (character controlled by the user)

I've played with `RealityComposer` but it doesn't seem like the tool for creating complex landscapes or characters for this use case (I could be wrong). seems more of a prototype tool for fast POC

I'm assuming that there are tools such as `sketch` and open `usdz` files (tried googling and searching but nothing substantial came up)

What is the appropriate workflow for this type of app (game) development?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of two options:

A. Programmatically add and control models within the AR View. This will require a decent knowledge of Swift and a lot of looking around for examples and reading the docs for RealityKit.

B. Switch over to Unity. Unity would be a lot easier to work with and is designed for games (Which is what it sounds like you want to do). Bonus is your game/app will be cross platform.